# What is making this sticky nav jump when activated?

Tags: css

For this site [here](https://www.exactmats.com/products/FS-100?make=Fisker&year=2014) on scrolling, a `scrolled` class gets added to the top nav like so.

```
<nav class="top-menu scrolled">
```

Just when that happens the bottom of the nav jumps down then up, and the items within the nav jump down then up.

I can see that when the class gets added, various new paddings get applied.

What I can't work out is what padding to change to make the transition to the sticky header smooth.

Can you help please? Thanks!

Comment: Why do not use `position: fixed` for that menu?

Comment: @lolka_bolka the top nav when scrolled is `position: fixed`